# Is there an API for Dart's web-based debugger?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Dart. I have been playing around with the browser-based debugger with a simple command-line app like so:

```sh
flutter pub global run devtools 
dart --observe test_file.dart --pause-isolates-on-start
```

I navigate to `127.0.0.1:9100`, enter the URL provide by the `dart` tool and everything works.

Is there any official documentation for how the browser is able to command the VM to step through code, set breakpoints, etc? I cannot find any.

I would like to integrate Dart debugging support into an editor I'm writing and I'm guessing that since the browser can manipulate the VM there must be some sort of API in existence. Is this public or private?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the Dart Debugger API, which is already being used by most of the debuggers that understand Dart/Flutter.  Docs for that may be found at [the debugger api docs][1]`https://pub.dev/documentation/chrome_dev_tools/latest/domains_debugger/DebuggerApi-class.html`